# select to_number ('12,500') from dual

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

am trying to work on  a big data and i want to convert a string to number in order to perform calculations on it. how do i go about its
some of the row content is '12,500' and '8,876'

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is to replace the comma.  Either:

```
select to_number(replace('12,500', ',', '')) from dual
```

or

```
select to_number(replace('12,500', ',', '.')) from dual
```

depending on whether the comma is a decimal point separator or  not.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass a number format in the TO_NUMBER functions.

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('12,500,000.90', '999,999,999.90') 
  FROM dual;
```